# Run tests with a set of marks, which selected based on command line parameter's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-markers

I have following tests:

```
@pytest.mark.hardware
@pytest.mark.feature1
@pytest.mark.feature2
def test_device1():
    pass

@pytest.mark.hardware
@pytest.mark.feature1
def test_device2():
    pass

@pytest.mark.hardware
@pytest.mark.feature2
def test_device3():
    pass
```

Aim: If I specify on command line argument:  `pytest --device device1` , I want that only tests with marks feature1, feature2, hardware will be run. Similarly: argument device2 will only evoke tests with marks hardware and feature1 etc. And if there is no argument, tests without marks will be run.

In the conftest.py I have:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    group = parser.getgroup("filter")
    group.addoption(
        "--device",
        action="store",
        help="specify the device",
    )
```

I have found that `pytest_collection_modifyitems` could possibly help, but I don't know how to select list of marks to be run based on command line parameter's value. Thanks in advance for any help.

I have tried, but didn't work:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    if config.getoption("--device") == 'device2':
        for item in items:
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.hardware)
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.feature1)
```

Comment: You are on the right track, you now have to filter the `items` list. However, the filter criteria are not quite clear. For example, if `--device=device1` is passed, should a test be executed if it has _all_ listed marks (`feature1`, `feature2` and `hardware`)? Or should it have _any_ of them (`feature1`, `feature2` or `hardware`)? Also, what do you mean by _tests without marks will be run_? In your example, would none of the tests be executed if `--device` is not supplied?

Comment: If ```-device=device1``` is passed, test with all marks (feature1, feature2, hardware) should be executed. If no device's name is specified, the tests without any marks should be run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to filter the `items` list based on the `device` option condition. Example impl:

```
def marker_names(item):
    return set(m.name for m in item.iter_markers())


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    device_markers = {
        "device1": {"feature1", "feature2", "hardware"},
        "device2": {"feature1", "hardware"},
    }

    device_option = config.getoption("--device")

    if device_option is None:
        items[:] = [item for item in items if not list(item.iter_markers())]
    else:
        allowed_markers = device_markers[device_option]
        items[:] = [item for item in items if marker_names(item) == allowed_markers]
```

You can also skip tests instead of leaving them out. Example impl:

```
def marker_names(item):
    return set(m.name for m in item.iter_markers())


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    device_markers = {
        "device1": {"feature1", "feature2", "hardware"},
        "device2": {"feature1", "hardware"},
    }

    device_option = config.getoption("--device")

    if device_option is None:
        for item in items:
            if list(item.iter_markers()):
                item.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip("has no markers"))
    else:
        allowed_markers = device_markers[device_option]
        for item in items:
            if marker_names(item) != allowed_markers:
                item.add_marker(pytest.mark.skip(f"has some markers missing for {device_option}"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when I run: ```pytest --device device2 -v```, the test for device1 is also being executed: 
```tests/test_new.py::test_device1 PASSED tests/test_new.py::test_device2 PASSED```
I assume that it is because the marks for device2 are subset of marks for device1. Could you please help with omitting this undesired behavior?

Comment: @Maria I have updated the answer that will only allow the tests that have the exact markers required by the `device` option.

Comment: thank you very much. Now it works as expected. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it possible to use/combine this solution in case: ````pytest -m hardware````?  So that I will run all hardware tests at once?

Comment: @Maria you can access the value of `-m` option via `config.option.markexpr`. Then combine it with the `--device` option using the required logic (one passed, the other not etc).